# Can and should pip install to a packages folder?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm coming from a .Net and Node background where packages from the package manager e.g. NuGet or NPM get installed into a specific /packages folder.

I'm learning python and when I do a `pip install` my packages either end up in a global store or I can tell pip to put them into a specific place.

Is it good practice to put them into a separate folder or does that upset the Zen of python?

I want to do this so I can docker ignore that folder and then `pip install` them inside the docker container based on my production operating system from a `requirements.txt` file.

Is there a good reason I shouldn't do this? Why does Python not do this as default as it seems to be a clean and portable approach to package management?

Comment: I think it's based more on your need. I usually pip install things like tensorflow, matplotlib globally as I know I have to use them frequently

Answer (score 0):

Usually you install them in the default location or within a python virtual environment.

[virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Do the virtual environment when you don't want to clutter up your default python environment.